# Knockout not observable array length inside if block

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have one 'not observable' array of objects in view-model and I want to render some div-s according to the array.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: sequences">
    <!-- ko if: $parent.sequences.length-1 > $index -->
        <div>Some content </div>
    <!-- /ko -->        
</div>
```

Code above should render div for all elements except the last one, but it does not work, I did not get any error, I do know what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` is an observable, so you need to use `$index()`:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: sequences">
    <!-- ko if: $parent.sequences.length-1 > $index() -->
        <div>Some content </div>
        <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->        
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhL2vhx0/).

Comment: Thanks, that is it. I thought that mistake is in the first part of condition, because I try it with solution:
  
<!-- ko if: $parent.sequences.length-1 === 3 -->   

and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visible binding for this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: sequences">
    <div data-bind="visible: $parent.sequences.length-1 >  $index()">
      Some content 
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it also works, but 'namesv' answer the best fit my question and I accept his answer :)